# Symfony2 entityaudit: Add field on revision table

Tags: forms, symfony

I have 2 entities in my bundle that are audited via [simplethings/entity-audit](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit).
I would like to add a field to REVISIONS table call "reason". Every time a user updates or delete an entity, he/she needs to especicify an reason for doing that (why updating/deleting) via form, and this reason should be associated to the entity revision.

How would you guys do it? I dont have much experience in OOP.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for adding field you need to add field in your database like 'ip' next you change your bundle in file "logRevisionsListener.php"

```
 private function getRevisionId()
    {
        if ($this->revisionId === null) {
            $this->conn->insert($this->config->getRevisionTableName(), array(
                'timestamp'     => date_create('now'),
                'username'      => $this->config->getCurrentUsername(),
                'ip'      => $this->config->getCurrentUsername(),(not correct just for test it give me the user name)
            ), array(
                Type::DATETIME,
                Type::STRING,
                Type::STRING
            ));
.
.
}
```

I added here the ip field and change your Revision.php file by adding your field with the getter method